# conditional join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have a table `id1`, `id2`, `type`. `type` is an enumerated value containing a name of another table.
I'd like to preform a `join` with the name of the table of `type`.
For example:

```
switch($type)
case 'table1':
   join table1;
   break;
case 'table2':
   join table2;
   break;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 26):

You can't do it directly like that... you can do something like this though (not very pretty...):

```
SELECT
t.id,
t.type,
t2.id AS id2,
t3.id AS id3

FROM t
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t.id AND t.type = 't2'
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t.id AND t.type = 't3'
```

Comment: Does mysql search for a row in table t3 if t.type is t2?

Comment: +1 for this nice solution, but you could have pointed out, that putting the the condition into the `ON` clause does the trick. I first missed that point and thought this query fetches all rows from both tables (maybe more than one row each, if you not use an unique key) and then you just have to ignore the columns that were `JOIN`ed by mistake. But this way you get `NULL`s where the condition is false.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. Thanks.

Comment: Combined with something like `IF(t.type= 't2', t2.id, t3.id) as type_id` in the selected fields, as proposed by Ilan, it is perfect, thanks! 

Answer (score 9):

ugly way:

Table Types, T1, T2:

```
SELECT ... FROM Types, T1 , where Types.ID=T1.Types_ID AND Types.TYPE='TABLE1'
UNION
SELECT ... FROM Types, T2 , where Types.ID=T2.Types_ID AND Types.TYPE='TABLE2'
```

Comment: Isn't that just "the way"?  Stop using my name.

Comment: It's "A" way. It looks ugly, I was hoping there was a better. But then again most SQL beyond "SELECT * FROM X" looks ugly to me ;)

Comment: Steve stop fighting with yourself :P

Comment: As doing left joins do have some drawbacks, (not excluding things for one), this is the one for me!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to previous answer:
You can combine the two left joins results by using `IF` statement:

```
IF(t.type= 't2', t2.id, t3.id) as type_id
```

You can see another [mysql conditional joins](http://www.mysqldiary.com/conditional-joins-in-mysql/) example at `mysqldiary.com`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement such a thing with Laravel Query Builder. I was preparing a library and shouldn't rebuild the whole query, I wanted to utilize Eloquent as much as possible so I could only add a join to the query. This could be a little closer to what you want but also a lot uglier than you would expect:

```
SELECT
    `comments`.*,
    `commentable`.`created_at` AS `commentable_created_at`
FROM
    `comments`
LEFT JOIN ((
    SELECT
        *,
        CONCAT('post_', `id`) AS `morphed_key`
    FROM
        `posts`)
UNION (
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT('image_', `id`) AS `morphed_key`
FROM
    `images`)) AS `commentable` ON
    CONCAT(`comments`.`commentable_type`, '_', `comments`.`commentable_id`)= `commentable`.`morphed_key`
```

The point of using this way is that you are now able to add `WHERE` clauses like `WHERE commentable.owner_id=?`

Comment: Would you care to share your Eloquent code? I have a situation where I am trying to return a field from my related tables (morphed relationships) but having a hard time!

Comment: @Zakalwe i didn't use Eloquent with this. If you can elaborate your issue maybe I can help.

Comment: Sorry. It was the Query Builder I was working with but managed to solve this. Thank you for the offer of help though.