# Joining on a CASE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, associations, polymorphism

Trying to implement polymorphic associations in MySQL. I thought the code could look something like this:

```
SELECT
...
FROM
resource
LEFT JOIN (
     CASE resource.owner_type
       WHEN 'meeting' THEN
         ( SELECT * FROM meeting ) as owner
       WHEN 'todo' THEN
         ( SELECT * FROM todo ) as owner
      END)
```

But the CASE is causing a syntax error. How can this be rewritten correctly?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql

Comment: One problem is ensuring that you have a consistent set of columns in the output - you can't have the meeting rows containing a different number of columns from the todo rows.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't substitute joins on a row-by-row basis - but I believe this is a solution to what you are trying to achieve:

```
SELECT
...
FROM
resource
LEFT JOIN meeting ON resource.id=meeting.resource_id
WHERE resource.owner_type='meeting'
UNION
SELECT
...
FROM
resource
LEFT JOIN todo ON resource.id=todo.resource_id
WHERE resource.owner_type='todo'
```