# how to write conditional left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables named `user` and `userFriend`. I want all user from user table, and specific member from userFriend table. Then I want to join both of them...

```
user
userID   userName
1         aaa
2         bbb
3         ccc
4         ddd
5         eee

userFriend
userFriendID userID friendUserID
1              1      2
2              2      3 
3              1      4
4              4      2
```

So if my userID = 1,
then I want result like

```
userID   userName userFriendID  friendUserID      
2          bbb        1          2
3          ccc        NULL       NULL
4          ddd        3          4
5          eee        NULL       NULL
```

so in this way I want conditional for 2nd table, I only want to join 2nd table having userID = 1 with 1st table using left join.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql

Comment: Could you layout your code a bit better (use the formatting help). At this moment it seems you have userID, userFriendID and friendUserID, while I believe you only need two ID's.

Comment: Could you please post your datamodel ? I believe such a request implies that there's an issue there instead.

Answer (score 5):

It's an unconventional thing to ask for... but this gives you the results you want.

```
SELECT u.userID, u.userName, uf.userFriendID, uf.friendUserID
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN userFriend uf ON u.userID = uf.friendUserID AND uf.userID =1
WHERE u.userID !=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want you dont need a query from both tables. Just using userFriend will give you the data. You'll need the user table for names only.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM userFriend
WHERE friendUserID = ?
```

this will give you all users that have that specific friend that you need.
Optionally you can add a INNER JOIN to see what are the names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.userID, u.name 
FROM userFriend f
INNER JOIN users u ON u.userID = f.userID
WHERE friendUserID = ?
```

**UPDATE**
A comment about your structure. You don't need the userFriendID. The combination of userID and friend ID can be your key.

UPDATE of the query

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN userFriend f on u.userID = f.userID
WHERE f.friendUserID = ?
```

This will return you all users that have the friend X. The left join is not important in this query. This specific condition is making it irrelevant.

To get exactly what you want you need to execute this.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM userFriend f
    WHERE friendID = 4
) x ON u.id = x.userId
```

It can be done using a subquery, but I dont think is the most logical way of organizing your tables.