# mysql conditional join depends on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to implement a generic notification system.. I have a data structure like this;

```
notification_base:id,type,object
notificiation_sub:id,user_id,not_base_id,lastNotifyTime
notification_action:id,user_id,not_base_id,action,creationDate
```

So basic scenario is, user create a notification base item by post a status, or upload a photo  and etc.(ın this case status,photo refers to type field in notification_base table and object_id is post_id or photo_id depends on type)
Then user subscribe for this notification_base item..(user 3 subscribe notification_base 5 and last notify time x)

After that another user touch this notification_base item. (for example commenting a status or like a photo)
This action is recorded in notification_action table (user 5 make action 'like' on 12/02/2011)..

What I want is fetch the notification_base items from user subscription if last notifiytime smaller than a notification action  then join them with notification_action..
I can succeed it with this sql ;

For user id 3;

```
select * from notification_action
                inner join notification_base on notification_action.not_base_id = notification_base.id
                inner join notification_sub on notification_action.not_base_id = notification_sub.not_base_id
                where notification_sub.user_id = 3 and notification_sub.lastShowDate < notification_action.creationDate ;
```

result is almost what i want, for example

user x did 'action' on your object which has 'type' and object_id at time t

but I also want to join on object_id depends on type.. So I can actually learn which object touched.. But as you can see type is dynamic, if type = post object id refers post_id on post table, if type=photo object id refers photo_id on photo table and etc..

I try to do it something like this but got some syntax error;

```
SELECT *
FROM notification_action
INNER JOIN notification_base
    ON notification_action.not_base_id = notification_base.id
INNER JOIN notification_sub
    ON notification_action.not_base_id = notification_sub.not_base_id CASE notification_base.type
            WHEN 'photo'
                THEN (
                        INNER JOIN photo
                            ON photo.id = notification_base.object_id
                        )
            ELSE (
                    INNER JOIN post
                        ON post.id = notification_base.object_id
                    )
            END
WHERE notification_sub.user_id = 3
    AND notification_sub.lastShowDate < notification_action.creationDate;
```

I know that it's not correct, it's like pseudo code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql - you might be able to union many queries together, for example, and the left join strategy would work, but it would also require a lot of joins if you have many tables.

Comment: ok now I got the error "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" becuase table structure are different from each other and I also need to get different data from each table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can't conditionally create joins across tables. The best way to do is to use `LEFT JOIN` and use you `CASE` in your `SELECT` statement. You must have specify common columns you want to show,

```
SELECT *,
        (CASE notification_base.type
            WHEN 'photo'
            THEN photo.columnName1
            ELSE post.ColumnName1
        END) as ColumnName1,
        (CASE notification_base.type
            WHEN 'photo'
            THEN photo.columnName2
            ELSE post.ColumnName2
        END) as ColumnName2
FROM notification_action
    INNER JOIN notification_base
        ON notification_action.not_base_id = notification_base.id
    INNER JOIN notification_sub
        ON notification_action.not_base_id = notification_sub.not_base_id
    INNER JOIN photo
        ON photo.id = notification_base.object_id
    INNER JOIN post
        ON post.id = notification_base.object_id
WHERE notification_sub.user_id = 3
    AND notification_sub.lastShowDate < notification_action.creationDate;
```