# Decide to do LEFT JOIN on which table based on CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. I want to left join with one of the tables based on certain condition. I want to do something like this:

```
IF (Projects.paymentType==1)
    LEFT JOIN ProjectBudgetFixedPrice ON (Projects.budget=ProjectBudgetFixedPrice.id)
ELSE
    LEFT JOIN ProjectBudgetPerHourPrice ON (Projects.budget=ProjectBudgetPerHourPrice.id)
```

I have created the following, but it is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM Projects LEFT JOIN
(IF (Projects.paymentType==1,ProjectBudgetFixedPrice,ProjectBudgetPerHourPrice))
    ON 
(IF (Projects.paymentType==1,Projects.budget=ProjectBudgetFixedPrice.id,Projects.budget=ProjectBudgetFixedPrice.id))

WHERE (Projects.statusCode=3 OR Projects.statusCode=4) AND Projects.suspended='N' AND (Projects.paymentType=1 OR Projects.paymentType=2)
```

Any help or suggestions please?

Comment: if or iif that is iif I think so

Comment: @Koushikveldanda Yes, that is IIF

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948812/mysql-conditional-join-depends-on-a-column

Comment: Build the query dynamically as a string and execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a UNION.

Something like

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Projects
  LEFT JOIN
    ProjectBudgetFixedPrice
    ON Projects.budget = ProjectBudgetFixedPrice.id
WHERE
  Projects.paymentType = 1
  AND ((Projects.statusCode = 3 OR Projects.statusCode = 4)
  AND Projects.suspended = 'N'
  AND (Projects.paymentType = 1 OR Projects.paymentType = 2))
UNION
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Projects
  LEFT JOIN
    ProjectBudgetPerHourPrice
    ON Projects.budget = ProjectBudgetPerHourPrice.id
WHERE
  Projects.paymentType <> 1
  AND ((Projects.statusCode = 3 OR Projects.statusCode = 4)
  AND Projects.suspended = 'N'
  AND (Projects.paymentType = 1 OR Projects.paymentType = 2));
```

HTH