# How to format Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an issue with a query I have written. It starts by calculating the following values and putting each summation grouped by da_no into a individual temporary table.

Goal
Goal Balance
Soft Pledge
Soft Pledge Balance
Hard Pledge
Hard Pledge Balance
Raised to Date

For some reason I cannot figure out how to format the query so that results are given regardless of if any of the temporary tables are empty. I've noticed that if I re-order the joins the query yields a result but I need a result if any of the columns are populated.

EXAMPLE ONE: Yields nothing

```
SELECT
COALESCE(Goal, 0.00) AS 'Goal',
COALESCE((Goal - RaisedToDate),0.00) AS 'GoalBalnce',
COALESCE(SoftPledge,0.00) AS SoftPledge,
COALESCE(SoftPledgeBalance,0.00) AS SoftPledgeBalance,
COALESCE(HardPledge,0.00) AS HardPledge,
COALESCE(HardlePledgeBalance,0.00) AS HardlePledgeBalance,
COALESCE(RaisedToDate,0.00) AS 'RaisedToDate',
da.da_no, TG.da_no
FROM
donations_accounts da
JOIN TEMP_GOAL TG on da.da_no = TG.da_no
JOIN TEMP_RAISED_TO_DATE TRTD ON da.da_no = TRTD.da_no
JOIN TEMP_HARD_PLEDGE_BALANCE THPB ON da.da_no = THPB.da_no
JOIN TEMP_SOFT_PLEDGE_BALANCE TSPB ON da.da_no = TSPB.da_no
JOIN TEMP_HARD_PLEDGE THP on da.da_no = THP.da_no;
```

EXAMPLE TWO: YIELDS ONE RECORD

```
SELECT
COALESCE(Goal, 0.00) AS 'Goal',
COALESCE((Goal - RaisedToDate),0.00) AS 'GoalBalnce',
COALESCE(SoftPledge,0.00) AS SoftPledge,
COALESCE(SoftPledgeBalance,0.00) AS SoftPledgeBalance,
COALESCE(HardPledge,0.00) AS HardPledge,
COALESCE(HardlePledgeBalance,0.00) AS HardlePledgeBalance,
COALESCE(RaisedToDate,0.00) AS 'RaisedToDate',
  da.da_no
FROM
donations_accounts da
JOIN TEMP_HARD_PLEDGE THP on da.da_no = THP.da_no
LEFT JOIN TEMP_GOAL TG on da.da_no = TG.da_no
LEFT JOIN TEMP_RAISED_TO_DATE TRTD ON da.da_no = TRTD.da_no
LEFT JOIN TEMP_HARD_PLEDGE_BALANCE THPB ON da.da_no = THPB.da_no
LEFT JOIN TEMP_SOFT_PLEDGE_BALANCE TSPB ON da.da_no = TSPB.da_no;
```

Goal, GoalBalnce, SoftPledge, SoftPledgeBalance, HardPledge, HardlePledgeBalance, RaisedToDate, da_no

0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 5000.00, 0.00, 0.00, 2352

The major problem is I don't know which temporary table will have a value in it and which one wont so it's difficult to determine while tables to left join from. Please let me know if there is another way I can write this script to get the correct result set. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `LEFT JOIN` for them all?

Comment: we were stumbling around with some `conditional joins` with `left joins` last nite, seems to be the route.

Comment: When I use a LEFT JOIN it shows ever single da_no and I've tried limiting by greater than 0.00 but for some reason it doesn't recognize it as a 0.00 or a null

Comment: @drew so should i just a "conditional join"?

Comment: every one is different of course, but check out line 3,4,5 of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13080097/1816093)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
COALESCE(Goal, 0.00) AS 'Goal',
COALESCE((Goal - RaisedToDate),0.00) AS 'GoalBalnce',
COALESCE(SoftPledge,0.00) AS SoftPledge,
COALESCE(SoftPledge - SoftRaised, 0.00) AS 'SoftPledgeBalance',
COALESCE(HardPledge,0.00) AS HardPledge,
COALESCE(HardPledge - HardRaised,0.00) AS HardlePledgeBalance,
COALESCE(RaisedToDate,0.00) AS 'RaisedToDate',
da.da_no
from donations_accounts da


LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(pl_debit), 0.00) AS 'HardPledge', pl.da_no FROM pledges pl WHERE pl_status = 1 AND pl.e_no = 22386 GROUP BY da_no) H on H.da_no = da.da_no
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(eg_goal), 0.00) AS 'Goal', da_no FROM events_goals WHERE e_no = 22386 GROUP BY da_no) g on g.da_no = da.da_no
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(disb_amount), 0.00) AS 'RaisedToDate', da_no FROM disbursements d LEFT JOIN contacts c ON d.c_no = c.c_no WHERE d.disb_status = 1 and c.c_status = 1 AND e_no = 22386 GROUP BY da_no) R on R.da_no = da.da_no
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(sp.sp_softpledge), 0.00) 'SoftPledge', sp.da_no FROM soft_pledges sp JOIN events_cohosts ec ON sp.ec_no = ec.ec_no LEFT JOIN contacts c on ec.c_no = c.c_no WHERE sp.da_no IS NOT NULL AND ec.ec_status = 1 AND sp_status = 1 AND c_status = 1 AND e_no = 22386 GROUP BY da_no) s on s.da_no = da.da_no
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(disb_amount), 0.00) AS 'SoftRaised', d.da_no FROM disbursements d WHERE disb_status = 1 AND b_no IS NOT NULL AND b_no <> 0 AND e_no = 22386 GROUP BY da_no) sb on sb.da_no = da.da_no
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(disb_amount), 0.00) AS 'HardRaised',pl.da_no FROM pledges pl JOIN disbursements d ON d.c_no = pl.c_no  WHERE pl_status = 1 AND d.disb_status = 1 AND pl.e_no = 22386 AND d.e_no = 22386 GROUP BY da_no) hb on hb.da_no = da.da_no

where 
(HardPledge > 0.00 
or Goal > 0.00 
or RaisedToDate > 0.00 
or HardRaised > 0.00
or SoftPledge > 0.00
or SoftRaised > 0.00);
```