# How to put a condition before to join the table in mysql sql?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

How to put a condition before to join a table ..
i want to put a condition to `(INNER JOIN job_views ON job_views.job_id = job.job_id )` this inner join.

if `job_views.job_id` exists only this join will occur otherwise no need to join.

How to solve it please help?

```
SELECT
            job.job_id,
            job.company_id,
            job.job_title,
            job.mini_description,
            job.job_description AS experience,
            job.salary,
            job.added_date,
            company.company_id,
            company.company_url,
            company.company_name,
            job_type.job_type,
            mst_location.location_name,
            job_location.location_id,
            COUNT(job_views.view_id) AS no_views,                                
            mst_industry.industry_title,
            company_img.img_title,
            company_img.img_file_name
      FROM
            job
            INNER JOIN job_location ON (job_location.job_id=job.job_id AND job_location.location_id IN (SELECT location_id FROM mst_location WHERE mst_location.location_name LIKE '%Sri%'))                             
            INNER JOIN company ON company.company_id = job.company_id
            INNER JOIN job_type ON job_type.job_type_id = job.job_type_id
            INNER JOIN mst_location ON mst_location.location_id = job_location.location_id                  
            INNER JOIN mst_industry ON company.industry_id = mst_industry.industry_id
            INNER JOIN company_img ON company.company_id = company_img.company_id

            INNER JOIN job_views ON job_views.job_id = job.job_id           


      WHERE       
           (job.job_title LIKE '%soft%' OR
            job.mini_description LIKE '%Admin%') AND
            company_img.active_flag = 1
        ORDER BY
                job.job_title ASC
```

Comment: a conditional join. never saw one. I suspect we will

Comment: then do u have any idea to solve this context?

Comment: found some stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest (not sure best) here will be use LEFT JOIN instead

```
LEFT JOIN job_views ON job_views.job_id = job.job_id
```

Comment: left join seems to be an approach from what I am reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql