# Foreign keys from 2 tables make a PK in the 3rd

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

[image]

Hi, Can the Accounts table get its values from the SA & CA tables the fields SA and CA being the FK's constraints in the Accounts table?

The logic requires that I go like this and not the other way round. i.e. not build Accounts first as a supertable and then create the other two from there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of *inheritance* and *supertable* as you suggest. It is not an OOP. So, create your tables with Foreign Key constraints and insert your data manually.

A Foreign Key value can be NULL. Though typically not a great idea. You might want to collapse your table from 3 down to 2 or 1 with a `type` column.

You may want to not have an Accounts table. What is even the purpose of it other than replication of information. Granted, it can handle more granularity, but don't over-populate your design with unnecessary tables.

If you are insistent on having separate Savings and Checking tables, and an Accounts table, the only way to pull off the Accounts table with FK's is with the use of NULLS. And, as mentioned, that is not recommended. The reason why? It is like saying *It must be one of these* ... except in the case that I don't care. And we should care about our data.

Resist the urge to have FK's `NULL`. One way to accomplish that is to have an accounts table, and join on other tables knowing only some will succeed. A [Conditional Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255553). Achieved via `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: > the only way to pull off the Accounts table with FK's is with the use of NULLS  do you mean that the Accounts field should be allowed to be NULL for the two FKs to work ?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. And what sort of FK is that anyway? A hack and shameful one! Resist the urge ! It is always, I mean always, a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Just wanted to try it once to see if it worked. Then please suggest how can I achieve that what  I am trying to. i.e. to create the Accounts table from the savings and current accounts tables ( even at the risk of replicating data). Thank you

Comment: I just did answer this question related to `NULL` so this question is over. That is how it works and how we roll here. So, it is called an upvote and Answered with a Green check mark.

Comment: Sure i'll upvote this and mark it as answer Drew, however I would still be at a loss as to how this can be achieved and the design be acceptable if not good at the same time. If you can elaborate this slightly more i'ld be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I would be happy to. You are always welcome to elaborate on your details in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) anytime and I will put a 2 to 3 table recommended schema idea together for you. But you need better details for that to happen