# How to set the relationship between tables to set value of a column form another table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table  **Bills** with:

- IDkey
- cost
- **objectDefinition**

And I have different table for each type of object

Table **ObjectA**
 - ID
 - Name
 - Location

Table **ObjectB**

- ID
- Weigth

I want the **objectDefinition** field to "link" to a filled column of objectX. In other words if the Bill has an objectA the objectDefinition should have all the information related to an objectA

What's the name of this relation, any links with helpful information?

Comment: search for FOREIGN_KEY relations

Comment: it is a conditional join that uses `left join`s. google "stackoverflow mysql conditional join" . Might be great with 3 conditional tables. A pain in the keester if you have hundreds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditional join in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql)

Comment: a.k.a. often a poor db design