# Entity having random relations with other entities

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, relational-database

I have a case where an entity (profession) may or may not have relations with other entites.

I might have a user that has housekeeping as a profession,  while another user has cooking as a profession but we have to specify what international kitchens he cooks in, so we have X is a cook in both spanish and asian kitchens, Y is in the housekeeping.

The conditional relation with other entities depends on the business type of the profession.

I have the following tables:

-- User:  Id,  Name,...

-- Profession:  Id,  title,  linked_entity_name

-- User_Profession: user_id, profession_id,entity_id

The entity id will be zero in the table User_Profession in case the profession was not linked to an entity.

Is this approach efficient in terms of table normalization, performance and data search in the website?

What would be the best practice where an entity may or may not have relations?

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fullName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `profession` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `linked_entity_name` varchar(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_profession` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
    `profession_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
    `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `kitchen` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `kitchen_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `kitchen_origin` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `kitchen_desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece75

Comment: What's the cardinality of the relationship between `User & Profession`? If `1 to many` then I think it's the best practice to keep a separate table like you did.

Comment: Yes a user can have multiple professions @1000111

Comment: what does this mean: *The entity id will be zero in the table User_Profession in case the profession was not linked to an entity.*

Comment: ^ that means it has no intersect row I hope

Comment: @Drew In the case where the user is in housekeeping, his row in table user_profession will have column entity_id value as zero

Comment: in that case See **Section2 /  What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you :p

Comment: @Drew, I have added a fiddle

Comment: ah you're the best. Immediate upvote for that :p

Comment: `user_profession.entity_id` 0 means no info, 1 and 2 map to kitchen?

Comment: @Drew that is true

Comment: yeah that won't work because as you say it may not be kitchen table stuff, it could be housekeeping or accounting

Comment: 3 ways come to mind. (1) a common professions table with common info for a join like worktype, location ... (2) conditional joins with `left joins` to independent tables like kitchen (and all of them !) but that doesn't scale well and it is ugly [this link here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255553) nice for like 3 tables, not 100. (3) use [EAV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) which some people love and it is almost necessary sometimes. Slow.

Comment: @Drew, You mean by approach (1) a header-detail style for the table ? I will elaborate the second and third approaches later on and will get back to you.. Thanks for your time..

Comment: Can you please post an elaborated answer with examples, I know you're good with such answers?

Answer (score 0):

Minutes ago I answered a question with the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650275/3658753) I would provide here.

In short, create a table or tables to contain the details of each profession as needed. Create a kind of intersection table to connect each user with their profession. Of course, the profession data will be contained in different tables for different professions so the profession side of the intersection table cannot directly reference the profession data tables.

So...place the FK in the profession table referencing back to the profession side of the intersection table using a profession designator to maintain data integrity. Details in the link above.

Comment: I have been analyzing the method you proposed, I have a bit different case here, the customer is always linked to a profession.. where would this go in your schema? Besides, how will it be efficient in terms of performance if the user is searching for all customers that are spanish cooks.. Can you please give a detailed example that suites my case after you get a small review of the business requirements to get to all the details?

Comment: If you have additional requirements, post them so we all have an opportunity to answer.

Comment: Its the same as the question, but the point is a customer might have a profession without details (such as housekeeping), another customer might be a Spanish and Asian cook.. I need to consider these cases. Besides, It seems a heavy query is needed for search.. or you think we can achieve good performance with this ERD?

Comment: There could be professions without details. The hyrid intersection table contains a profession indicator. If it contains 'H' (Housekeeping), you know there are no other details and the ID is null. If it contains 'C' (Cook), you know there are details in the CookDetails table identified by the value in the ID field. The CookDetails table itself could be normalized into multiple tables -- that makes no difference.

To search for Asian Cooks, start the search at the details table(s), then go to the customer table for that data. Should be very fast.