# Join Tables with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 tables let say Table1,Table2  and Table3.i have to join Table1 with either Table2 or Table3 according to a condition.

```
|------------|---------------|
|      id    |  Name         |
|------------|---------------|
|      1     |  facebook     |
|------------|---------------|
|      2     |  twitter      |
|------------|---------------|

|------------|---------------|-------------|
|      id    |  tab1_id      |   value     |
|------------|---------------|-------------|
|      1     |  1            |    val1     |
|------------|---------------|-------------|
|      2     |  2            |    val3     |
|------------|---------------|-------------|


|------------|---------------|-------------|
|      id    |  tab1_id      |   value     |
|------------|---------------|-------------|
|      1     |  1            |    val5     |
|------------|---------------|-------------|
|      2     |  2            |    val6     |
|------------|---------------|-------------|
```

DDL:

```
create table tbl1 (id int,  Name varchar(10));
insert into tbl1 values
(1,'facebook'),
(2,'twitter');

create table tbl2 (id int,tab1_id int,  value varchar(10));
insert into tbl2 values
(1,1,'val1'),
(2,2,'val3');

create table tbl3 (id int,tab1_id int,  value varchar(10));
insert into tbl3 values
(1,1 ,'val5'),
(2,2 ,'val6');
```

Here i need a join that if my first table `'Name'` is `facebook` table 1 should join with `Table2` and  if my first table '`Name`' is `Twitter` table 1 should join with `Table3`
I tried below query

```
SELECT tab1.*
from Table1 as tab1
case 
        when tab1.name='facebook' then left join Table2 on {condition} 
        when tab1.name='twitter' then left join Table3 on {condition}
```

Comment: show your query, what are you trying?

Comment: I am trying case when statement...but its showing error....l used...
case when tab1.name='facebook' then left join Table2
when tab1.name='twitter' then left join Table3

Comment: @SandeepNambiar add your query which you are currently trying to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditional join in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `T1`.`Name`, 
(CASE WHEN (`T1`.`Name` = 'facebook') THEN `T2`.`value` 
WHEN (`T1`.`Name` = 'twitter') THEN `T3`.`value` END) AS tab3_value 
FROM table1 T1 
LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON (`T2`.`tab1_id` = `T1`.`id` AND `T1`.`Name` = 'facebook') 
LEFT JOIN table3 T3 ON (`T3`.`tab1_id` = `T1`.`id` AND `T1`.`Name` = 'twitter') ;
```

Can you try the above query, I tested this query out.

[Here is a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d9cc6/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select *,
       case when name = 'facebook' then
         (select value from tbl2 where tab1_id = t1.id)
       else
         (select value from tbl3 where tab1_id = t1.id)
       end value
from tbl1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
with dt
(select *, namekey='facebook' from table2
union 
select *, namekey='twitter' from table3)

select * from table1
inner join dt on table1.Name=dt.namekey
```