# How to conditionally Join tables in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Hie,

I have 3 tables namely `Accounts`, `Companies` and `Freelancers`. The accounts table holds the `email`, `password` and `account_type` fields where if `account_type` values is an `ENUM('companies','freelancers')` .  I want to know how I can write a query that Joins with `Companies` Table if `account_type`  fields is equal to `companies` else should Join with `Freelancers`

Comment: I assume you cannot change any tables? Because if you could i would put all entries from companies and freelancers into a single table and add the account-type enum-column to that table as well. Then you can simply join using this column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql <- duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditional join in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the data to one table,

1. you can simply use a `union` to bind 2 results sets that you get from joining 2 tables.

   ```
    SELECT * FROM users Accounts a
    LEFT JOIN Companies c ON c.account_id = a.id  
    WHERE a.account_type = 'companies'

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM users Accounts a
    LEFT JOIN Freelancers f ON f.account_id = a.id 
    WHERE a.account_type = 'freelancers'
   ```
2. You can join the tables according to the ids by getting the ids to one table.

   ```
   SELECT
   Accounts .id,
   Accounts .type,
   Companies .account_id AS id2,
   Freelancers .account_id AS id3

   FROM Accounts 
   LEFT JOIN Companies ON Accounts .id = Companies .account_id AND Accounts .type = 'companies'
   LEFT JOIN Freelancers ON Freelancers .account_id = Accounts .id AND Accounts .type = 'freelancers'
   ```

I hope this will help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
SELECT Accounts.column1, 
       COALESCE(Companies.column2, Freelancers.column3), -- common column
       Companies.column4,                                -- specific column
       Freelancers.column5                               -- specific column
FROM Accounts
LEFT JOIN Companies ON Companies.account_id = Accounts.id 
                   AND Accounts.account_type = 'companies'
LEFT JOIN Freelancers ON Freelancers.account_id = Accounts.id 
                   AND Accounts.account_type = 'freelancers'
```