# if else situation in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, join

I have a view that I use at work.

My goal is:

- If "data on row " = 'petrol' then columns should be fetched from "A table inner join B table"
- If "data on row" = 'diesel' then fetch from "C table inner join D table"

Is that possible in same column at the view query? (plsql)

cant i use if else construction for this? problem still not solved because The tables I want to use do not have a common columns

if a =1 then select SAMPLE from sample_table

if a <> 1 then SELECT ANOTHER DIFFRENT from another different unique table

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can make use of `union all` in such scenarios..but unless providing sample data and expected result would be difficult to imagine all at once.

Comment: i provided sample below

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained. Put what is needed into your post, not just at a link.

Comment: In SQL we join to get all pairs of rows from 2 tables. ON or WHERE keep pairs we want. ]SELECT outputs a row for each of those rows. So: What pairs of rows do you want to keep & what function of each pair do you want to return? We can union for all rows of 2 tables. PS Returning 2 different joins on conditioin is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.) Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditional join in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1255492/3404097)

Comment: union all doesnt solve my problem because i use these queries in the complicated view. when i use union all results doesnt match truely

Comment: The answers on that post tell you how to do this. They are the same as the answers on this post. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS That comment is not clear.. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0):

One method would uses `left join`s and `coalesce()` for this.  Your question doesn't provide many details, but the idea is:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b.datas, d.data) as datas
from a left join
     b
     on . . . and a.column = 'diesel' left join
     c
     on . . . and a.column <> 'diesel' left join
     d
     on . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the columns you require from the tables `B` and `D` are of the same data type then you can use `UNION ALL` with a filter in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT a.col1,
       a.col2,
       b.col3,
       b.col4
FROM   a INNER JOIN b ON ( a.id = b.id )
WHERE  a.other_column = 'petrol'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.col1,
       a.col2,
       d.col3,
       d.col4
FROM   a INNER JOIN d ON ( a.id = d.id )
WHERE  a.other_column = 'diesel'
```