# Using If else in SQL Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I need to know if an IF can be inserted into a SQL query.

If the value of a column is X make a JOIN with a table but if it is Y make a JOIN with another table.

It's like:
Select * from Table1
If (Table1.value = 1) then JOIN Table2
else JOIN Table3

can this be done?

Comment: Not an option..

Comment: You can try UNION ALL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditional join in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255492/conditional-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You would use `left join`.  Something like this:

```
select . . .
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.column = 'X' and <other conditions> left join
     t3
     on t1.column = 'Y' and <other conditions>
where t1.column in ('X', 'Y')
```

Comment: ```
select cargaid, cargaartartic,articcodigo, articdescripcion, lprecioimporte, cargaart1provc, provdescripcion 
            
from MCARGAARTICULO
            
JOIN articulos on cargaartartic = articcodigo
JOIN proveedor on cargaart1provc = provcodigo
JOIN listaprecio on cargaartartic = lprecioartcod and cargaart1provc = lprecioprovcod

where cargaid = :carga
```
But if MCARGAARTICULO.VALUE ==99 
It should not JOIN listaprecio, It shoul JOIN ArtList...

how do i do this?

Comment: @JoseZarate . . . This answers the question asked here, which is quite general.  I might suggest you ask a *new* question if you have more details and cannot apply the general answer.